# Why does my /n code not work when I have typed it correctly?

Tags: python

I am trying to run this python code:

```
print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
symbols = ["!","@","#","$","%","&","*","(",")","/","+"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
amount_letters = int(input(f"How many letters would you like?/n"))
amount_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?/n"))
amount_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?/n"))
```

However, it doesn't meet my satisfaction as I want the user's input on the next line but the /n code doesn't work.

```
Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!
How many letters would you like?/n (This is where the user input goes)
(But I want it to go here.)
How many symbols would you like?/n (This is where the user input goes)
(But I want it to go here.)
How many numbers would you like?/n (This is where the user input goes)
(But I want it to go here.)
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up `\n` and `/n`.

`\n` gives you a newline.
`/n` only prints just that - '`/n`'.